# Call a Function on SharePoint Online Site Title Change

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, azure-functions, webhooks

I have a requirement to call an API whenever the site Title is changed in SharePoint online. Can someone help me on how to implement this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the features SharePoint Online currently does not have. You can raise your concern/request at https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/.

However, you can do the workaround by creating a scheduled job (Azure scheduled function, or Windows Task Scheduler, or Scheduled Flow/Automate) which will read the current site title and compare it with the previous site title. Not immediate like webhooks, but close enough.

Assuming you're taking Task Scheduler (with PowerShell), you can run every 1 hour:

- Read the site's title and store it in a file for the first run.
- Next run: read the site's title to compare with the site's title stored in the file. If it's different, then call something.